# cant populate a list in a Foreach Request.Files loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

i'm having issues adding items to a list with the foreach loop iterating through Request.Files. it seems to only add the last object in the list? even though my database is saving the entries of all the files, and the individual files are getting saved also.

here's the controller code that i am posting to (from dropzone.js):

```
public ActionResult SaveDropzoneJsUploadedFiles()
{   
    List<FileObject> files = new List<FileObject>();

    foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

        // custom file object
        var uploadFile = new FileObject();

        // files come through, i get the name
        uploadFile.Name = file.FileName;

        // add to list (only adds last object?)
        files.Add(uploadFile);

        // files save 
        file.SaveAs(uploadFile.Path);
        // db context saves
        db.Files.Add(uploadFile);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

the fileObject class is as follows:

```
    public class FileObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public string Hash { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try initializing the "httpPostedFilebase" outside the Foreach loop

Comment: Please post the definition of the FileObject class, especially if you are overriding the `GetHashCode` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your FileObject class a custom class?  If so, are you overriding the GetHashCode method in it?  If so, ensure that the GetHashCode method returns a unique value for each new instance.

**UPDATE**:

Based on what you've posted, I don't see a reason why the list with only contain one item.

Have you tried debugging and stepping through the loop and watching the list to ensure that it's contents are not being reset or items removed?  Also add a watch for `files[0] == uploadFile` and make sure that the value is either false or throws an exception (during the first pass when the list is empty).

**UPDATE 2**:

Based on the new comment from the author, it sounds like the controller method is being called multiple times.  If so, try the following code changes to prove that is the case, but only with the understanding that I really don't think that this is a good idea:

```
public class DropzoneController
{

    private static List<FileObject> files = new List<FileObject>();

    public ActionResult SaveDropzoneJsUploadedFiles()
    {   

        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

            // custom file object
            var uploadFile = new FileObject();

            // files come through, i get the name
            uploadFile.Name = file.FileName;

            // add to list (only adds last object?)
            files.Add(uploadFile);

            // files save 
            file.SaveAs(uploadFile.Path);
            // db context saves
            db.Files.Add(uploadFile);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

}
```

If the files list begins to behave as expected, then your files are coming in over multiple calls.  I don't think that it is a good idea to have a static list of these files hanging around though as it is certainly code smelly.

Comment: i've posted the fileobject class - not overriding GetHashCode, cheers

Comment: having a closer look at it in VS2015 i think it's because the files are being passed in and it's running multi-threaded... i cant seem to work out how to handle this in any of the thread safe collections

Comment: Whoa, hold on a sec.  Is `SaveDropzoneJsUploadedFiles` being called multiple times from the outside caller?  If so, then that is why the list only ever contains one item.

Comment: @jessemillman I've updated my answer with one more thing to try.  It's not thread safe, but you could replace `List<FileObject>` with a thread safe alternative if you need to.  Also, I don't think that having a static lying around like that unmanaged is a good idea, so beware.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[i];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately i get the same result - only 1 file gets added to the list.

Comment: i've added the fileobject class :)

Comment: can you try this `files.Add(new FileObject(){Name = file.FileName})`

Comment: Hi Narek - i tried this also and unfortunately it's the same result